# Cannot change one a colour

Tags: html, css

I need to change the colour of one link.

I generally have no problem in managing the `a` colour, but in this case I do not know what to do.

This is how the link appears:

[image: Blue link]

and this is the style that I see when I inspect the element within Safari or Chrome:

[image: CSS Style]

As you can see, the computed style defines the correct colour, but the link is still shown using blue. If I go to the 'Computed Style' tab and check 'Visited' the colour becomes correct. So the problem is the default link colour.

The html code follows:

```
<div id="top-header">
<table id="top-header-table">
<tr>
<td id="icon"><i class="fa fa-th fa-2x"></i></td>
<td id="headings"><h1>Page Title</h1><h2>Subtitle</h2></td>
<td id="controls">
       <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>Username<br/>
       <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i><a href="logout.php"> ESCI</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

The CSS is:

```
table#top-header-table a {
    color: WhiteSmoke !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table#top-header-table a:visited {
    color: WhiteSmoke !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I made thousands of attempts. I cannot change its colour even if I add an`id` to the `a` element. I am only able to change its colour using an inline style.

Is there someone who can explain what the problem is?

No other link in my pages is shown using blue.

**EDIT. I added !important as suggested but nothing changed.**

Comment: try `color: red!important;`

Comment: Done. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be getting overwritten somewhere. Check out the "Computed" tab in your dev tools to find out. Usually it is because you have it defined on the top of the CSS file and something below it is snagging it. CSS files are interpreted from top to bottom.

Comment: After inspecting the computed rules, I realised that the 'visited' colour is working (I checked 'visited'): the default colour is not working.

Comment: Thank you. I could not understand what was overwriting it so I just moved the two rules at the end of the CSS file and now it works

Comment: You're welcome. CSS can be a tricky beast. I recommend reading up on the basic prioritization rules. Trust me, you'll actually begin to love CSS.

Answer (score 0):

So judging by your image this specific part is misbehaving ?

```
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i><a href="logout.php"> ESCI</a>
```

the fa or fa-power-off class might be overruling your a styling.

set the appropriate styling for the `a` on the `fa-power-off` class.

Comment: The `<i …></i>` element is an icon in font-awesome. If I delete that element nothing changes. In other places, however, those elements do not cause any problem.

Comment: I made a fiddle from your post and it works, so it must be overwritten in your css. http://jsfiddle.net/QZz9E/

Comment: Thank you. I could not understand what was overwriting it so I just moved the two rules at the end of the CSS file and now it works.